# DNS client refuses to update Windows DNS server

Tags: windows, domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-dns

Server 2016- DC and client
Windows Integrated DNS

Not sure why this is happening. I join a computer to AD and it updates DNS with its record.

The IP changes on the client but the record never updates. I go to the client and run `ipconfig /registerdns` but the ip on the dns server still doesn't change. I deleted the record from the DNS server and ran `ipconfig /registerdns` and it registered the record with the new IP.

Why didn't it update it? why did i have to delete it?

Comment: One possible cause is that there was already a DNS entry with the same name, belonging to a older computer or perhaps an older installation of Windows on the same computer.

Comment: Your client has fix IP, or DHCP provided? Secured DNS or not? Please note that create the record and update it are different actions that may have different permissions.